# why panel show more space from left when list is inserted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I make left panel in this fiddle.It is stick with left side.Please check image.
http://jsfiddle.net/eHded/1676/show/
[image]
Now I used this plugin (insert nested list )
http://dbushell.com/2012/06/17/nestable-jquery-plugin/
[image]

It show more space from left side.And when screen become small it also show a part of list .check (images).I don't know why it is occurring  ? it is due to css conflict ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Nm5br/1/[image]

```
$('.slider-arrow').click(function(){
    var newWidth = $(this).parent().width() * 0.8;

    if($(this).hasClass('show')){        
    $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({            
      left: "+=" + String(newWidth)
      }, 700, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
      $(this).html('&laquo;').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    }
    else {      
    $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
      left: "-=" + String(newWidth)
      }, 700, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
      $(this).html('&raquo;').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');    
    }
});
```

It should not display any thing when panel is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's padding on the body tag. Change:

```
body { font-size: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 1.75em; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif; }
```

to

```
body { font-size: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 1.75em 0; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif; }
```

updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/Nm5br/4/

However, after taking a look at the images again, if you want to keep the padding then you can add a `margin-right: 30px;` to the `dd-item` class.

Updated using `margin-right`: http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/Nm5br/6/

And by editing the padding on the body to `0.50em`, you get something that more closely resembles your first image: http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/Nm5br/7/